# The offsetWidth, scrollWidth,ClientWidth Property is not working for Html Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am having this control  and trying to get the offsetWidth,clientWidth and scrollWidth..

```
<span class="label-block" style="height: 19px; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;">
<label for="ctl00_Form_PlaceHolder_chkIsAnnualSelfInsuranceRenewalCertificaterequired" id="tid" style="background-color:Transparent;">
Annual Self Insurance Renewal Certificate Required
</label>
 </span>
```

My code..

```
var a=$("#tid").offsetWidth;
var b=$("#tid").clientWidth;
var c=$("#tid").scrollWidth;

alert("offset Width =" +a);
alert("client Width =" +b);
alert("scroll Width =" +c);
```

The alert message displays as **"Undefined"** 
I have tried in Chrome and IE11 both results the same.

Comment: try logging those variables to make sure you have something in them first.

Comment: the variables are created so it is not possible to have a value in them earlier

Comment: You are mixing javascript and jquery. offsetWidth for example is used on a js object and you are trying to use it on a jquery object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `$("#tid")` returns an jQuery-object (with the DOM-label-element wrapped inside), but the three `width` are properties of the DOM-element itself. So you have to get the element itself:

```
var tid = $("#tid").get(0); // or:
var tid = $("#tid")[0]; // or with native javascript:
var tid = document.getElementById("tid");
```

Now you have the element itself stored in var tid (it's better than writing three times $("#tid")) and can do:

```
var a = tid.offsetWidth;
var b = tid.clientWidth;
var c = tid.scrollWidth;
```

According to the comments: these jQuery-methods works also in Chrome when element is `display: inline;`

```
var $tid = $("#tid"); // for jQuery-methods we need the jQuery-object

var e = $tid.outerWidth(); // corresponds to offsetWidth
var f = $tid.innerWidth(); // corresponds to clientWidth
```

Since jQuery has no direct equivalent for element.scrollWidth and inline-elements don't give reliable values for `scrollWidth` it would be best to set them to `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: In chrome, if your element is display inline then it will return 0. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/w4k0rnpo/1/ to verify

Comment: IE 11 the all the three properties are returning the value as offsetWidth =242, scrollWidth=540 but in Chrome the offsetWidth is returned as 242 and scrollWidth as 0

Comment: @Gowthaman I have updated my answer. In your case the best solution would be in **CSS**: `#tid {display: inline-block;}`.